# StackOverflowError - Java Recursion

Tags: java

I am getting stackoverflow errors with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    generateSequence(13);
}

private static void generateSequence(int num) {
    System.out.println(num);
    while(num != 1) {
        if(num % 2 == 0) {
            generateSequence(num/2);
        }
        generateSequence(num*3+1);
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: For any n that is not 1, you are going to call `generateSeq(n*3+1)`. Surely, this cannot terminate, except by luck when the int overflows. But the stack is not that deep.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Look again. A call to `genSequence`, as it stands can *never* return unless the argument is 1, and the *while* is not the only reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a base case there. Also, are you sure you need a `while` loop there instead of an `if`? I guess you should change that method to:

```
private static void generateSequence(int num) {
    System.out.println(num);

    if(num == 1) return;  /* Add a base case */

    if(num % 2 == 0) {
        generateSequence(num/2);
    } else {
        generateSequence(num*3+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry I actually had an if instead of a while so I changed that. What do you mean by adding a base case?

Comment: If the intention is to generate the collatz sequence, then the second recursive call should go into an `else` branch.

Comment: Oh wow. That was a super trivial oversight on my part. It's so obvious when I think about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> while(num != 1)

But value of `num` is never changed, when defining recurrance relation why use loop??

Try:

```
private static void generateSequence(int num) {
    System.out.println(num);

    if(num == 1) {
        return;
    }

    if(num % 2 == 0) {
        generateSequence(num/2);
    } else {
        generateSequence(num*3+1); // I think it should be in else ;)
    }
}
```

Comment: The missing *ele* is indeed the reason for getting the stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The maximal recursion depth is not bound in your program. Here is a sequence of choices for

- branch a (`generateSequence(num/2);`)
- or branch b (`generateSequence(num*3+1);`)

that generates infinite recursion depth:

```
Choice   num
     b   13
     a   40
     a   20
     a   10
     b    5
     a   16
     a    8
     a    4
     b    2
     b    7
     a   22
     b   11
     a   34
     b   17
     a   52
     a   26
     repeat from beginning...
```

From the [javadoc of StackOverflowError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html):

> "[StackOverflowError is] thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an
>   application recurses too deeply."

Therefore your function throws an StackOverflowError.

Answer (score 0):

Very good question, I hope you are expecting the reason instead of giving other idea to get output for your code. Just I have shared my knowledge with yours ....

When num is getting 2

while (num != 1) {

```
if(num % 2 == 0) {
       // Call again generateSequence(1) and Enter into one more inner while loop. 
       // In that time num is 1 and terminated from inner while loop
       // But still num is 2 in outer while loop and Loop is getting next step
       // generateSequence(2*3+1) to execute and getting one more while loop. 
       // So It's keep on entering into the inner while loop ... 
       // That's why you are getting **StackOverflowError**
}
generateSequence(num*3+1);
```

}